# How to set the send and receive buffer size of a Java nio socket

Tags: java, size, buffer, nio

Is there any way to set the send buffer and recieve buffer of a sock channel in Java Nio? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

socketChannel.socket().setSendBufferSize() etc.